# Why won't two html elements separate?

Tags: javascript, css

I've been messing around with random code to try to get better with HTML and CSS, so I've been trying to make a moving figure.

The problem is that the square (head) is attached to the stick (body/torso) and I can't get them off.

How would I separate the two?

```js
// move controls //
var up = false,
    right = false,
    down = false,
    left = false,
    x = window.innerWidth/2-130/2,
    y = window.innerHeight/2-130/2
document.addEventListener('keydown',press)
function press(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 38 /* up */ || e.keyCode === 87 /* w */) {
    up = true
  }
  if (e.keyCode === 39 /* right */ || e.keyCode === 68 /* d */) {
    right = true
  }
  if (e.keyCode === 40 /* down */ || e.keyCode === 83 /* s */) {
    down = true
  }
  if (e.keyCode === 37 /* left */ || e.keyCode === 65 /* a */) {
    left = true
  }
}
document.addEventListener('keyup',release)
function release(e){
  if (e.keyCode === 38 /* up */ || e.keyCode === 87 /* w */) {
    up = false
  }
  if (e.keyCode === 39 /* right */ || e.keyCode === 68 /* d */) {
    right = false
  }
  if (e.keyCode === 40 /* down */ || e.keyCode === 83 /* s */) {
    down = false
  }
  if (e.keyCode === 37 /* left */ || e.keyCode === 65 /* a */) {
    left = false
  }
}

// attach controls to body //
function gameLoop() {
  var square = document.querySelector("square")
  if (up) {
    y = y - 3
  }
  if (right) {
    x = x + 3
  }
  if (down) {
    y = y + 3
  }
  if (left) {
    x = x - 3
  }
  square.style.left = x+'px'
  square.style.top = y+'px'
  window.requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop)
}
window.requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop)
  
// attach controls to rest of body //
function gameLoopStick() {
  var stick = document.querySelector("stick")
  if (up) {
    y = y - 3
  }
  if (right) {
    x = x + 3
  }
  if (down) {
    y = y + 3
  }
  if (left) {
    x = x - 3
  }
  stick.style.left = x+'px'
  stick.style.top = y+'px'
  window.requestAnimationFrame(gameLoopStick)
}
window.requestAnimationFrame(gameLoopStick)
```

```css
square {
    border: 8px solid black;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
    top: 100px;
}
stick {
    border: 5px solid black;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 200px;
    top: 200px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <title>Moving Cubes :)</title>
  </body>
  
  <body>
    <square id="square"/></square>
    <stick id="stick"/></stick>
  </body>
  <script>
    
  </script>

</html>
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen? You move both of them when you hold down "right", for example...

Comment: I don't get what you want, what do you expect when you press one of the arrow? do you want to only move the square?

Comment: Try adding `margin-left: -105px;` to the stick.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing this is what you want? You are trying to adjust the stick with `position:absolute`, but you're also using absolute positioning to move the whole figure. Absolute positioning isn't what you want if you're just trying to move something over in relation to its neighboring element. Try `margin` instead.

```js
// move controls //
var up = false,
  right = false,
  down = false,
  left = false,
  x = window.innerWidth / 2 - 130 / 2,
  y = window.innerHeight / 2 - 130 / 2
document.addEventListener('keydown', press)

function press(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 38 /* up */ || e.keyCode === 87 /* w */ ) {
    up = true
  }
  if (e.keyCode === 39 /* right */ || e.keyCode === 68 /* d */ ) {
    right = true
  }
  if (e.keyCode === 40 /* down */ || e.keyCode === 83 /* s */ ) {
    down = true
  }
  if (e.keyCode === 37 /* left */ || e.keyCode === 65 /* a */ ) {
    left = true
  }
}
document.addEventListener('keyup', release)

function release(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 38 /* up */ || e.keyCode === 87 /* w */ ) {
    up = false
  }
  if (e.keyCode === 39 /* right */ || e.keyCode === 68 /* d */ ) {
    right = false
  }
  if (e.keyCode === 40 /* down */ || e.keyCode === 83 /* s */ ) {
    down = false
  }
  if (e.keyCode === 37 /* left */ || e.keyCode === 65 /* a */ ) {
    left = false
  }
}

// attach controls to body //
function gameLoop() {
  var square = document.querySelector("square")
  if (up) {
    y = y - 3
  }
  if (right) {
    x = x + 3
  }
  if (down) {
    y = y + 3
  }
  if (left) {
    x = x - 3
  }
  square.style.left = x + 'px'
  square.style.top = y + 'px'
  window.requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop)
}
window.requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop)

// attach controls to rest of body //
function gameLoopStick() {
  var stick = document.querySelector("stick")
  if (up) {
    y = y - 3
  }
  if (right) {
    x = x + 3
  }
  if (down) {
    y = y + 3
  }
  if (left) {
    x = x - 3
  }
  stick.style.left = x + 'px'
  stick.style.top = y + 'px'
  window.requestAnimationFrame(gameLoopStick)
}
window.requestAnimationFrame(gameLoopStick)
```

```css
square {
  border: 8px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  top: 100px;
}

stick {
  border: 5px solid black;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  top: 200px;
  margin-top: 116px;
  margin-left: 56px;
}
```

```html
  <square id="square" /></square>
  <stick id="stick" /></stick>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try some css

```
square{
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

if you mean they're overlapping like in the snippet, maybe try z-index:

```
stick{
 z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: Thank you symlink and sujio! That helped me out, sorry if I worded it weird :V